# How to differentiate between O(n^2) and O(2^n) in dynamic programming with 2 parameters with memoization?

Tags: python, dynamic, big-o

For example in https://leetcode.com/problems/stickers-to-spell-word/description/

Here is a solution with memoization

```
class Solution(object):
    def minStickers(self, stickers, target):
        """
        :type stickers: List[str]
        :type target: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        memo = {}
        def is_better(target, sticker):
            original_count = len(target)
            for c in sticker:
                target = target.replace(c, "", 1)
            return target, original_count != len(target)
        def dp(target, idx):
            if idx >= len(stickers):
                return float("inf")
            if len(target) == 0:
                return 0

            if (idx, target) in memo:
                return memo[(idx, target)]

            op1 = dp(stickers, target, idx + 1)
            new_target, is_use = is_better(target, stickers[idx])
            op2 = float("inf")
            if is_use:
                op2 = dp(stickers, new_target, idx)
            if op2 != float("inf"):
                op2 += 1
            memo[(idx, target)] = min(op1, op2)
            return memo[(idx, target)]
        result = dp(stickers, target, 0)
        if result == float("inf"):
            return -1
        return result
```

Why is the above function have a big O of `2^T * S * T`

T is the target length
S is the number of characters in the sticker

Where is 2^T coming from?

My thinking is that 2^T becomes S*T after introducing memoization, and since we only iterate through the combination of number of stickers and each character in T , the big O should be `# of stickers * T * O(comparing two strings)`?

A similar question is https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/description/

```
class Solution(object):
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        memo = {}
        def dp(i, sum_):
            if (i, sum_) in memo:
                return memo[(i, sum_)]
            if i == len(nums):
                if sum_ == target:
                    return 1
                return 0

            result = dp(i + 1, sum_ + nums[i]) + dp(i + 1, sum_ - nums[i])
            memo[(i, sum_)] = result
            return result
        return dp(0, 0)
```

Which is O(total_sum * length of numbers) essential O(n^2) , but both problem have two branching factor in each step , and no repeating sub problems due to memoization

Why is one exponential and one quadratic?
What am i missing here?

Comment: Please summarize what the code is doing here, not just with an external link. Questions should be self-contained, not dependent on other sites.